# Multithreading with Python/Flask/Waitress resulting in duplicate outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, waitress

I have a Python Flask Server that is given doc files on one route, saves them to a job specific folder, and then when all `.docx` files are uploaded a new route triggers a batch, multi-threaded job to convert them to PDF.

The issue is if I send a second request from the same client for a different job, the first job completes fine, but the second and subsequent process all the files requested in both the first and second job and copies them to the second or subsequent output folders.

The route:

```
@app.route('/docxgroupproc2',methods=['GET'])
def docgroupproc2():
    startTime=datetime.now()
    jobid=request.args.get('jobid')
    newPath, jobPath, outPath=paths('',str(jobid))
    localdata=local()
    localdata2=local()
    localdata.value=jobPath
    localdata2.value=outPath
    mtThread= Thread(target=mtconvDOCX.bleck, args=(localdata.value,localdata2.value),daemon=True)
    mtThread.setDaemon(True)
    mtThread.start()
    print("Thread Started")
    mtThread.join()    
    endTime=datetime.now()
    print(endTime-startTime)
    return ({'completed': "status"})
```

The multithreading module:

```
 def parseDOCS(outPath,file):
    comtypes.CoInitialize()
    word=comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
    word.Visible=False
    doc= word.Documents.Open(file,Visible=False)
    outFile = os.path.join(outPath,str(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0] + ".PDF"))
    try:
        doc.SaveAs(outFile, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
    except COMError:
        res = "FAIL"
    else:
        res = "SUCCESS"
    finally:
        doc.Close()
        word.quit()
    return    

        
def setupParse(dir,fileCounter=0,TotalFileCounter=0,fileslist=[]):
    "return number of files in dir"
    for files in os.scandir(dir):
        if files.is_file():
            fileCounter+=1
            TotalFileCounter=+1
            fileslist.append(files.path)
    text="DOCX Files" + " : " + str(fileCounter) + "\ntotal files: " + str(TotalFileCounter)
    print(fileCounter)
    #dictlist=map([(x,outPath) for x in [fileslist]])
    return text, fileCounter, TotalFileCounter, fileslist



def bleck(dir, outPath):
    text, fileCounter, TotalFileCounter, dictlist=setupParse(dir)
    pool=ThreadPool(4)
    #result=pool.starmap_async(parseDOCS,zip(dictlist, repeat(outPath)),chunksize=1)
    result=pool.map_async(partial(parseDOCS,outPath),dictlist)
    while not result.ready():
        print("\rNumber of Files Processed: {}".format(fileCounter-result._number_left+1), end='           ')
        pass
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return "completed"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def setupParse(dir,fileCounter=0,TotalFileCounter=0,fileslist=[]):
```

So that line was the problem.
Moving the declarations from the def line and then initializing them to the correct values inside stopped fileslist from being appended to by each thread/job.